# Count number of vowels in a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Im trying to create a method that counts the number of vowels in a string except there is a flaw in my code that I am unable to identify.

For example, if I put in the word fire, it prints out:

Vowels: uVowels: e

I'm not sure why its not printing out the number of vowels. Heres my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Counter
{ 
    // class variables shared by more than one method
    String prompt;
    static String strUserResponse;

    // main method
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        vowelCounter();
    }
public static void vowelCounter()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<strUserResponse.length();i++)
    {
        char v = strUserResponse.charAt(i);
         if (v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u'
         || v == 'A'|| v == 'E' || v == 'I' || v == 'O' || v == 'U')
        {
            System.out.print ("Vowels: " + v);
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: `Y` is feeling lonely... But, well, you aren't counting anything actually. Just printing the vowels.

Comment: @Tunaki Sometimes... ;-)

Comment: Unable to reproduce: 1) Question is not [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (it's *incomplete*, so not *verifiable*). 2) Prints `i` and `e` when given `fire`, so don't know where your `u` comes from.

Answer (score 3):

It is printing "Vowels" multiple times because you have that inside the for loop, so every time the if statement is true, it is printing "Vowels" along with the vowel you want. You can print "Vowels" before beginning the for loop to fix that (note, this is best under an assumption whatever you are checking will have vowels in it, otherwise it will just print "Vowels:" with nothing trailing).

You also forgot to declare a variable to keep track of the number of vowels.  Since you already are checking to print the vowels you see, you should add to that counter as you print each vowel you find looping through.

```
public static void vowelCounter(){
    int numVowels = 0;
    System.out.print("Vowels:")
    for (int i = 0; i<strUserResponse.length();i++){
        char v = strUserResponse.charAt(i);
        if (v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u'
          || v == 'A'|| v == 'E' || v == 'I' || v == 'O' || v == 'U'){
            System.out.print(" "+v);
            numVowels++;
        }
    }System.out.print("Number of vowels: "+numVowels);
}
```

EDIT: Also note that the call to print the number of vowels is outside of the for loop, otherwise you will just print 1 2 3 4 ...." whenever you are in the loop, and I am assuming that is not intended behavior.

Comment: I finally see what I did wrong and fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not counting the vocals. Your variable v is a char. You should have an acumulator and increment it.

```
int numberOfVowels = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<strUserResponse.length();i++){
        char v = strUserResponse.charAt(i);
         if (v == 'a' || v == 'e' || v == 'i' || v == 'o' || v == 'u'
         || v == 'A'|| v == 'E' || v == 'I' || v == 'O' || v == 'U')
        {
            System.out.println ("Vowels: " + v); //just print the vocal
            numberOfVowels++; //increment numberOfVowels
        }
}

System.out.println ("Total of Vowels is: " + numberOfVowels);
```

Edit: you can use println so you dont have this problem "Vowels: uVowels: e
"

it will print:

Vowels: u

Vowels: e

Comment: I think you mean "[vowels](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vowel)", not "[vocals](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocal)".

Comment: Thanks, i dont main english

Answer (score 0):

so I tried keeping the formatting and general structure of the code the same (using a class called Counter). Here is one way of doing this that's fairly straightforward (although keeping the class name Counter makes it seem a little wonky)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Counter
{
  // class variables shared by more than one method
  public String word; // Word to be check for vowels
  private static final char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}; // char[] of vowels to be checked against


  /*String prompt;
  static String strUserResponse;*/

  // main method
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Counter word = new Counter(); // Create new instance of Counter class
    word.word = args[0]; // Set the word of the Counter variable
    System.out.println(word.vowels()); // Print nubmer of vowels in word
  }
  /* Returns the nubmer of vowels in the word */
  public int vowels()
  {
    String lowerWord = this.word.toLowerCase(); // Make word lowercase to be able to check for uppercase vowels, too
    int count = 0;
    if (word.length() > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        count += (this.isVowel(lowerWord.charAt(i)) ? 1 : 0); // if the letter in the current iteration for the loop is a vowel, increase the count, otherwise, don't
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    for (char ch : vowels) {
      // If the character is a vowel, return true
      if (c == ch) return true;
      else continue; // continue so if the char is not a vowel it doesn't just return false
    }
    return false; // if no vowels are found, return false
  }
 }
```